# golang channel behaviour with for loops

Tags: go, goroutine

I'm curious about the behaviour of channels and how they work in relation to loops. Suppose I have the following code:

**Consumer**

```
tick := time.Tick(time.Duration(2) * time.Second)
for {
    select {
    case <-tick:
        p.channel <-true
    }
}
```

And I have a goroutine that has the following:

**Processor**

```
for {
    select {
    case canProcess := <-p.channel:
        // synchronous process that takes longer than 2 seconds
    case <-p.stop:
        return
    }
}
```

What happens when the **Consumer** pushes to the channel faster than the **Processor** can complete its synchronous process?

Do they pile up waiting for the **Processor** to complete or do they skip a "beat" as such?

If they pile up, is there potential for memory leaking?

I know I can put the synchronous process in a goroutine instead, but this is really to understand how channels behave. (i.e. my example has a 2-second tick, but it doesn't have to).

Comment: For the record, single-case select statements are never useful.  Just receive off the channel directly, it's mechanically identical to a select that only has a single case (and no default).  Also, the documentation for time.Tick annotates that it is a convenience wrapper for time.NewTicker, and the documentation for time.Ticker annotates that it will drop ticks to make up for slow receivers.  So if your processor is slow, the ticker will skip ticks until your consumer loop is ready to receive the ticks again.  https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

select will only invoke next time.Tick if previous case corresponding code was completed,
you can still have some lever by specifying size of channel i.e channel := make(chan bool,10)

See below:

```
func main() {

    channel := make(chan bool, 10)
    go func() {
        tick := time.Tick(time.Duration(1) * time.Second)
        for {
            select {
            case <-tick:
                fmt.Printf("Producer: TICK %v\n", time.Now())
                channel <- true
                }
        }
    }()

    for {
        select {
        case canProcess := <-channel:
            time.Sleep(3*  time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("Consumer: Completed : %v\n")
            fmt.Printf("%v\n", canProcess)
        }
    }
}
```